# Arduino IDE - Maximum serial COM ports

Tags: arduino-uno, wifi, communication

**What is the maximum number of serial ports (com) can Arduino IDE detect ?**

I need to connect 6 Arduino UNO Wi-fi at a time to make a small network and I use a 7 port USB hub for the same. The device manager shows 6 com ports detected but Arduino shows only 4 serial ports detected. Is there a limitation on the serial ports interfaced with the Arduino IDE ?

Comment: You could run 6 copies of the IDE to allow a Serial Monitor per board.

Comment: I've never had any success connecting the IDE to multiple boards, it seems to use a global for the Serial Port and so all instances program the same board.  It might have changed with the latest IDE, I haven't tried for a few months.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I found the solution. 

Inside the My computer -> Properties -> Device manager under ports I found that multiple Arduino's where assigned same COM values. 

Therefore, just go to properties of the COM and change them to COM values that are not used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your comments. I found the solution. Inside the **My computer -> Properties -> Device manager** under ports I found that *multiple Arduino's where assigned same COM values*. Therefore, just go to properties of the COM and change them to COM values that are not used

Comment: Cool! Indeed, a valid solution was to try another OS ;)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [last version of code for Arduino IDE](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/tree/master/arduino-core/src/cc/arduino/packages/discoverers), there are no limits of discovered Serial or Network devices since they are stored in a list (not limited as an array).

To discard problems, try with another operating system.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. From my findings, if I'm not wrong the maximum detectable serial port for Windows 7 is 255.